# The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying  to do a uni activity which involved writing the following program. I keep getting an error on line 27 where I've got `else  (employeetype == 2) {`, the error is as follows `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
    Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement`.

I'm new to java and don't really understand what I've done wrong here as the same assignment works in the if statement properly but not the else.

Could someone help me please?

```
import java.util.*;
public class TaskFive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please type 1 if you are hourly rated or 2 if you are a salesperson.");
        double employeetype = console.nextDouble();
        double pay;

        if (employeetype == 1) {
            System.out.println("Please enter your hourly rate:");
            double hourly = console.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Please enter the total hours you worked:");
            double hoursworked = console.nextDouble();

            if (hoursworked > 40) {
            double  overtimepay = hoursworked - 40;
             pay = (overtimepay * (hourly * 1.5)) + (40 * hourly);
            }
            else {
             pay = (hoursworked * hourly);
            }}

            else  (employeetype == 2) {
            System.out.println("Please enter your commission rate as a decimal:");
            double comrate = console.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter your sales value:");
            double sales = console.nextInt();

            pay = 500 + (sales * comrate);

            }

        double tax = (pay*.3);
        double netsalary = pay - tax;

        System.out.println("Tax: " + tax);
        System.out.println("Net Salary: " + netsalary);

        }

    }
```

Comment: `else  (employeetype == 2) {` doesn't mean anything, but it looks like you forgot to type `if` as in `else  if (employeetype == 2) {`

Comment: You need to initialize pay variable also e.g `double pay = 0;`

Comment: Thanks @Santosh I definitely also missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello friend in "if else" statement, "if" can check condition but "else" can not check condition, it only execute statement.so if you want to check a condition in "else" after "if" you have to change it to below code

```
 else if (employeetype == 2)
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I missed such a tiny thing!

Comment: Welcome,in programing there are lot of silly things we miss.It makes our skill better.I think.